# Loop over list of dictionaries and within list values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have a list of two dictionaries:

```
iter_list = [{0: [2, 1, 3], 
              1: [3, 2, 1], 
              2: [1, 2, 3], 
              3: [2, 3, 1], 
              4: [1, 2, 3], 
              5: [2, 3, 1]},
             {0: [2, 3, 1], 
              1: [1, 2, 3], 
              2: [1, 2, 3], 
              3: [1, 2, 3], 
              4: [2, 3, 1], 
              5: [1, 3, 2]}]
```

Each dictionary has 6 keys numbered 0 through 5.
I would like to loop through each dictionary one at a time in the order of the key and have the output be a pair with the key (ordered by the key value) and the first value of the corresponding list, the first value corresponding with the second key etc. followed by the key and the second value etc.  Hopefully the example output will clarify:

```
0 2
1 3
2 1
3 2
4 1
5 2
0 1
1 2
2 2
3 3
4 2
5 3
0 3
1 1
2 3
3 1
4 3
5 1
0 2 //2nd dictionary iteration 
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 1
0 3 
1 2
2 2
3 2
4 3
5 3
0 1
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 1
5 2
```

I've only been able to figure out how to loop through the first position of the first dictionary, but can't figure out how to use the [0] as an iteration variable to go through all positions in the value lists before moving on to the next dictionary.

```
for i in iter_list:
    for key, value in i.iteritems():
            print key, value[0]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why does it not end in 3,1,2?

Comment: The example would be much clearer if you used unique values rather than always the same few. And does it need to be that big?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I actually made it much shorter than what I originally had, but didn't want to have both list length of 2 and dictionary number of 2 to be confusing to see where the new iteration started.  The example I was working with was using permutations which is why I didn't use unique values, but definitely a good point! Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, in your case, you need to iterate the iter_list 3 times

```
>>> for i in iter_list:
...     for x in range(3):
...         for key, value in i.iteritems():
...             print key, value[x]
...
```

Output:

```
0 2
1 3
2 1
3 2
4 1
5 2
0 1
1 2
2 2
3 3
4 2
5 3
0 3
1 1
2 3
3 1
4 3
5 1
0 2
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 1
0 3
1 2
2 2
3 2
4 3
5 3
0 1
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 1
5 2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for answering! There are actually only two iterations, one for each dictionary. Our numbers diverge at the second round of key = 0, I have (0,1) and you have (0,2). This is because I want to go completely through the first dictionary before looping through the second, moving through the positions of each loop.

Comment: @HaifengZhang: If you swap the first two loops, you'd probably be correct.

Comment: @Shayna swap  `for x in range(3):`  and `for i in iter_list:`

Comment: @SuperSaiyan  agree. I misunderstood OP's point, I have edited my code

Answer (score 2):

A different approach using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) tricks:

```
from itertools import chain
packed_pairs = zip(*[[(k, v) for v in vs] for ds in iter_list for k, vs in ds.items()])
pairs = chain(*packed_pairs)
for pair in pairs:
    print pair[0], pair[1]
```

Output:

```
0 2
1 3
2 1
3 2
4 1
5 2
0 2
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 1
0 1
1 2
2 2
3 3
4 2
5 3
0 3
1 2
2 2
3 2
4 3
5 3
0 3
1 1
2 3
3 1
4 3
5 1
0 1
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 1
5 2
```

**Note:** make sure to use `pairs = list(pairs)` if you want to re-use `pairs`.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension should do:

```
>>> output_list = [[k, d[k][i]] for d in iter_list for i in range(3) for k in sorted(d)]: 
>>> for k, dki in output_list:
...     print k, dki
...
0 2
1 3
2 1
3 2
4 1
5 2
0 1
1 2
2 2
3 3
4 2
5 3
0 3
1 1
2 3
3 1
4 3
5 1
0 2
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 1
0 3
1 2
2 2
3 2
4 3
5 3
0 1
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 1
5 2
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you want to do this:

```
for i in iter_list:
    for j in range(3):
        for key, value in i.iteritems():
            print key, value[j]
```

assuming the values in the dictionaries have a fixed length of 3, otherwise you have to figure out where 3 comes from.
For example, it could be the *minimum* value length across all values of all dictionaries:

```
>>> min(len(v) for k,v in i.iteritems() for i in iter_list)
3
```